# How to add non-default parameters to a child method?

Tags: python, inheritance, pycharm, method-signature

I have a parent class with default and non-default parameters. The child class has the same method, and I would like to add one more non-default parameter.

```
class Parent:
    def func(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=1, arg4=2):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def func(self, arg1, arg2, arg_new, arg3=1, arg4=2):
        pass
```

Although this code works, PyCharm marks the child`s method and says: "Signature of method 'Child.func()' does not match signature of base method in class 'Parent'."

How can I solve this? What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Above code is working for me

Comment: It works. Just Pycharm mark this as a warning...

Comment: Best practice is to *not* do this. Your `Child` class breaks `Parent`'s interface. Maybe this override should really be a new method, or maybe `Child` shouldn't inherit from `Parent` at all.

Comment: Become familiar with the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). TL;DR: any child of a parent ***is*** its parent's type. You should be able to substitute objects of the same type without breaking anything. The function `def foo(o: Parent): o.func(1, 2)` will break depending on whether you pass it a `Parent()` or a `Child()`, which is an unsound type system. So: just don't.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot!